# How to open Windows Terminal in VS Code integrated mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-terminal

I have added below lines to `Terminal › Integrated › Profiles: Windows`:

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "WTP": {
          "path": "C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\wt.exe",
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "WTP",
```

But this opens Windows Terminal as an **external window**!

I want to open this terminal in integrated mode to have it **inside VS Code window**.

Comment: Related: [Can I use Windows Terminal as the integrated terminal in VSCode?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/faq#can-i-use-windows-terminal-as-the-integrated-terminal-in-vscode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Sercan comment, [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/faq#can-i-use-windows-terminal-as-the-integrated-terminal-in-vscode) state that it's not possible since VSCode is written in TypeScript while Windows Terminal is native code.

[image]